# How to unlimit spray jsonFormat

Tags: json, scala, spray

I'm implementing some rest API that use spray and akka The API should expose some kind of user CRUD. I'll use only create user in this question...

```
case class User(id:String, name:String)  
case class Register(user:User, registrationId:String) 

trait DefaultJsonFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport with MetaMarshallers {}

class RegistrationService(registration: ActorRef)
   (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) 
                   extends Directives with DefaultJsonFormats {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(2.seconds)
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat3(User)
  implicit val registerFormat = jsonFormat1(Register)
  implicit val registeredFormat = jsonFormat1(Registered)

  val route =
      path("register") {
          post {  handleWith { ru: Register => (registration ?   ru).mapTo[Registered] } }
}
```

Now Lets suppose that User class has 30 fields
  but there is no  jsonFormat30(...) 
How can I use such implicits for any case class object?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless which works with case classes >30 parameters just fine, expect somewhat longer compile times though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the methods in the `ProductFormatsInstances` trait, there are versions of `jsonFormat` up to 22 parameters. If you have a case class with more than 22 parameters, I see two immediate options. Suppose you have

```
case class Client(..., address: Address, telephone: Telephone, email: Email, ...)
```

- Options 1: reduce the number of parameters by breaking down the `Client` class into finer-grained classes taking fewer parameters.. For example, you can refactor to the following.

  ```
  case class ClientContact(address: Address, telephone: Telephone, email: Email)
  case class Client(..., contact: ClientContact, ...)
  ```
- Options 2: write a custom serialiser by implementing `RootJsonFormat`. See [here](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, It is API do I can't change the objects. About the option2 : could you please give an example wich classes trait to extend  in order to add implementations.

Comment: My earlier suggestion to write a 30 parameter `jsonFormat` in the same fashion as those in `ProductFormatsInstances` cannot work. Because of a limitation in the Scala language, the largest number of parameters a function can take is 22 (i.e. there is no `Function23` or higher in the scala package). If Option 1 is not viable, you should still be able to write a custom serialiser for your `User` class by overriding `RootJsonFormat`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking how to do that, but I'm quite new to scala. Could you please add an example for that.

Comment: Essentially, you need to tell spray how to map your domain objects to JSON and vice versa by implementing a `RootJsonFormat`. A good starting point is the documentation, in particular, the section about [other types](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types). I hope this helps.

Comment: RootJsonFormat override ( at least the example given )  https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types doesnt work because JsArray and Seq will get one into 22 parameters limitation