# How to serialize more than 22 fields with nested object in spray?

Tags: scala, spray

I can extend `RootJsonFormat` in order to support more than 22 fields on the case class. However, my case class also contains nested objects and Option[Int] and Option[String]. How can I serialize those? The nested objects do not have more than 22 fields. [I found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713834/parsing-more-than-22-fields-with-spray-json-without-nesting-case-classes) on SO but unfortunately, I cannot get it working. Not sure what was meant by `Tuple22` in the response.

Comment: Probably no, and more than 22 fields is basically a symptom of design issue

Comment: Explain what you tried and why you cannot apply the solution suggested in the link you mention.

Answer (score 1):

as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713834/parsing-more-than-22-fields-with-spray-json-without-nesting-case-classes)  said, you can `Providing JsonFormats for other Types`, that means you can make you case class serialized by override implement you own write/read method.

here is a [sample](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types) of how to approach it.